# Irreducible Curves over $k$ homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $X, X'$ be two irreducible curves over field $k$ endowed with Zariski topology.

Why are they then already homeomorphic, therefore isomorphic as **topological spaces**?

Comment: With curves you mean affine or projective ?

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio: That does not matter.

Comment: In every case there is an answer here :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293575/two-irreducible-plane-affine-curves-over-an-algebraically-closed-field-k-are-h?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/293575/two-irreducible-plane-affine-curves-over-an-algebraically-closed-field-k-are-h?rq=1 if $k$ is algebraically closed. If $k$ is not closed then the claim is false.

Comment: @MoisheCohen what fails about $k$ not algebraically closed? This seems true via base change to the algebraic closure and observing that the action of the Galois group is finite on every point.

Comment: @KReiser For instance, one curve can be empty.

Comment: @MoisheCohen what? How can a curve be empty? I agree that a curve may fail to have rational points, but that is very different from being empty. (For me, a curve is a scheme of dimension one, possibly with some other adjectives - but every curve has an affine open subset isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} R$ for some one-dimensional ring $R$. $R$ being one-dimensional implies it has at least two non-proper prime ideals and therefore $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is not empty.)

Comment: Yes, according to my definition a curve has dimension one. The question is what @KReiser pointed out: Are the irreducible curves homeomorphic if we consider them over a not algebraically closed field?